# Select Between Two Dates and from Two Tables in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

Please I need help with the right query for this query below...

```
SELECT 
    compute_num, 
    SUM(`shar_cr`) AS shar, 
    SUM(`thri_cr`) AS thri, 
    SUM(`vol_cr`) AS volun 
FROM `member_transacting` 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$end_date' 
RIGHT JOIN regist_members ON member_transacting.compute_num=regist_members.m_compute_num 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Basically, I want to select the sum of values in database table between two dates. And at the same time, I also want to fetch the same users information from the registered members table using their common identifier, which in this case is their computer numbers.

Expected Result

I want to be able to get the summation of values from member_transacting table plus also get grab the members name and phone number from the regist_members table.

I have tried out the above query on phpmyadmin but it didn't work. Instead it threw error, that the query is wrong. Please help.

MY PROGRESS THUS FAR
The Code Below From Professor Abronsius' Guide Works For Me

I just had to tweak it by adding GROUP BY and also requested specific field(full_name)from the regist_members table

```
    SELECT t.compute_num,
        m.full_name,     
        SUM( t.`shar_cr`) AS shar, 
        SUM( t.`thri_cr`) AS thri,
        SUM( t.`vol_cr`) AS volun
        FROM `member_trans` t
    JOIN `regist_members` m ON t.`compute_num`=m.`m_computer_no`
    WHERE t.`date` BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$end_date' 
    GROUP BY t.`compute_num` 
    ORDER BY t.`date` DESC
```

Even though the above code already gives me about 90% of what I want, I can't post it yet as answer because I still need a little help for it to be perfect.

THE HELP I NEED

Granted that the above code works well; it fetches the required results from both tables; but if I request more than one data from the regist_members table (e.g m.full_name, m.member_bank_name) at once it doesn't work. It only works if I leave the code as it is above. It doesn't allow me request for more data than what is in the above code. Please someone should guide.

Comment: There `join` should go before the `where` clause and you'll find it easier (?) to use table `aliases` rather than using the table name in the join conditions

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius can you share the right construct with me?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Let me try and get back to you

Comment: Please provide your tables structure, sample data and desired result [mre]

Comment: The tables are two with many data can you guide me on how to provide the table structure?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The Code you shared earlier with me helped me with some little tweaks. I just I added the values I needed from the regist_members table and also added the GROUP BY  clause  like Slava suggested and the query works exactly as I want. I will share the final working code as an answer. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I just updated my question can you please look into it if you can guide?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `GROUP BY` here:

```
SELECT 
    `member_transacting`.`compute_num`, 
    SUM(`shar_cr`) AS shar, 
    SUM(`thri_cr`) AS thri, 
    SUM(`vol_cr`)  AS volun 
FROM `member_transacting` 
JOIN `regist_members`
    ON `member_transacting`.`compute_num` = `regist_members`.`m_compute_num` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$end_date' 
GROUP BY `member_transacting`.`compute_num`
ORDER BY `member_transacting`.`compute_num` DESC;
```

Comment: MySQL threw error for the WHERE clause . It says the WHERE clause is unexpected, when I tested your query.

Comment: You right. Sorry. Fixed my answer.  Look here: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=29e9f8e4c2be14bb505b26567f001822&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to get my exact desired result from with Code Below...

```
           SELECT t.compute_num,
                        m.full_name,     
                        SUM( t.`shar_cr`) AS shar, 
                    SUM( t.`thri_cr`) AS thri,
                    SUM( t.`vol_cr`) AS volun,
                     m.member_bank AS bank_name,
                     m.member_account AS account_no
                    FROM `member_trans` t
                JOIN `regist_members` m ON t.`compute_num`=m.`m_computer_no`
                WHERE t.`date` BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$end_date' GROUP BY t.`compute_num` ORDER BY t.`date` DESC
```